# Converting a lambda expression in Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: vb.net, lambda

Simple question: How does this translate to VB.Net

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => listening = false);
```

listening is a variable on the class (boolean). Converters online didn't help and what we've come up didn't compile:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Function(listening) listening = False)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That would either not compile in C#, so please post the complete line.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: apparantly ); slipped of, fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a c# lambda like:

```
() => listening = false
```

the empty parentheses means that the lambda takes no parameters.  And since Dispatcher.BeginInvoke takes an Action, having no return value, in VB this would be a `Sub`, not a `Function`:

```
Sub() listening = False
```

so you'd have:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() listening = False)
```